# Elastic search Logstash How to configure UTC Time according to orcal time stamp

Tags: search, logstash, bigdata

I'am working with Elastic search Logstash ,catching updates from orcal data base into elastic search.
My problem ==> how to configure sql_last_start UTC time parameter with orcal time stamp.

This is my configration ====>

```
input{
jdbc {
     .
     .
     .
statement => "select * from cm.ELSAYED WHERE 'TIMESTAMP' > ':sql_last_start'"
}
}
filter {
date {
    match => [ "TIMESTAMP", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssssssssssssss Z" ]
    target => "TIMESTAMP"
    timezone => "UTC"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample value for TIMESTAMP?

Comment: oracle time stamp is ==> 08-AUG-16 12.26.03.796000000 PM                                                          -------------------------------------------------------------------                                                    sql_last_start is ===>      2016-08-08 14:44:22.037000000 Z

Comment: So which one ends up in TIMESTAMP?

Comment: two values are time-stamp, but the second is Using "UTC" time Zone and I want to convert the first into "UTC " time  in Logstash.

Comment: OK, one more try...  in the date{} filter, you're using a field called TIMESTAMP.  What value does this field contain before the filter is run?  Neither your original posting nor two other responses provides this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you [jdbc_default_timezone for input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_default_timezone)

add jdbc_default_timezone => "UTC" to input

Comment: You are right after adding this is working fine. Almost it's 2 days to resolve this thanks  a lot for your help